# Floor function with Multiplier

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I understand this: $f(x) = \lfloor x-4 \rfloor$
but how do you handle this $f(x) = 4\cdot\lfloor x-4 \rfloor$  . Do you distribute the $4$ then floor?

and the brackets denote floor.

Thank you

Comment: No, there is no further simplification. I suggest playing with http://www.desmos.com

Comment: You can simplify it to $4(\lfloor x\rfloor - 4) = 4\lfloor x\rfloor - 16$.

Comment: As it stands, your function will be a staircase, with the heights of the stairs $4$, and the width $1$.  The function $g(x)= \lfloor 4x - 16 \rfloor$ has stairs of height $1$ and width $1/4$.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean by 'handle'. If you want to know the order of operations to evaluate the expression you first subtract 4 from the input. Then you evaluate the floor function by selecting the greastest integer less than or equal to the resulting value. Finally you multiply that by 4.

Comment: Ok so Joshua and mjw that does look like you are distributing the 4 which makes perfect sense. Thank you everyone!

Comment: Are you asking about $4[x-4]$ or $[4x -4]$.  $[x +n] = [x]+ n$ con be easily seen it's straight rounding off integers but $[4x] = \begin{cases} 4[x]\\4[x] + 1\\4[x]+2\\4[x]+3\end{cases}$ depending and whether which of the following cases is true.  There is an $n$ so that $n \le x < n+\frac 14; n+\frac 14 \le x < n +\frac 12; n+\frac 12 \le x < n+ \frac 34;$ or $n+\frac 34 \le x < n + 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that for every $x$ there is a unique $n$ so that $n \le x < n+1$.

And that means there is also a unique $r: 0 \le r < 1$ so that $x = n + r$.

$\lfloor x\rfloor = n$ and $\{x\} = x -\lfloor x\rfloor = r$.

And we *always* have $x = \lfloor x\rfloor + \{x\}$.

....

Okay get that under our belt.

.....

For any integer $n$ we have

$\lfloor x- n\rfloor= \lfloor x \rfloor -n$ because......

$x-n = \lfloor x \rfloor +\{x\} - n= (\lfloor x \rfloor  - n) + +\{x\}$ and $0\le \{x\} < 1$ and $(\lfloor x \rfloor  - n)$ is an integer so

$(\lfloor x \rfloor  - n)\le (\lfloor x \rfloor  - n) +\{x\} =x-n < (\lfloor x \rfloor  - n)+1$ so

$\lfloor x -n\rfloor =\lfloor x \rfloor  - n$.

.....

So $4\lfloor x -4\rfloor= 4(\lfloor x \rfloor  - 4)=4\lfloor x \rfloor -16$